# Python modules won't import

Tags: python, python-module

I need to use `numpy` and `matplotlib` modules in my scripts. However, program crashes with `ModuleNotFoundError`. But when i run `pip freeze` those module names show up. When i'm trying to import them in the python command line it doesn't throw any exception. I ran `print(sys.path)` command and found those modules in the list of folders that it returned. Why they can't be imported in my script?

Comment: You should add the error you get and part of the script you using + OS used and IDE

Comment: What are the version of pip and freeze ? The modules installed using `pip` are for Python2 and those installed with `pip3` are for Python3.

Comment: do you have any folders named numpy or matplotlib?

Comment: Or files with those names?

Comment: @FedericoBaù Error i get is in mentioned in the post, it arises in plain `import` part of the scripts. My code editor is VSCode and OS is Win10.

Comment: @RemyJ Tried `pip3 freeze`, it returned me a list, that includes `numpy` and `matplotlib`, still can't import them.

Comment: Nevermind, just reinstalled the python and everything is working now.